# Audit logs if someone execute/ rerun failed job in Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

How do i know who executed or rerun the failed jobs in Azure devops pipeline which ws initially triggered by x user.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get Azure Pipeline build result, you can use the following rest API

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?definitions={definitions}&queues={queues}&buildNumber={buildNumber}&minTime={minTime}&maxTime={maxTime}&requestedFor={requestedFor}&reasonFilter={reasonFilter}&statusFilter={statusFilter}&resultFilter={resultFilter}&tagFilters={tagFilters}&properties={properties}&$top={$top}&continuationToken={continuationToken}&maxBuildsPerDefinition={maxBuildsPerDefinition}&deletedFilter={deletedFilter}&queryOrder={queryOrder}&branchName={branchName}&buildIds={buildIds}&repositoryId={repositoryId}&repositoryType={repositoryType}&api-version=6.0
```

For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0